# Get position of ListView scrollbar thumb on screen

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar

I am trying to get the location on screen of the ListView scrollbar thumb indicator. I'd like to position a label next to it and require the X,Y screen coordinates.

I attempted to get the height of the ListView and use the value from the 'firstVisibleItem' value obtained from the ListView OnScrollListener to position the label but due to the ListView items having varying heights this hasn't proved feasible.

Are there any other solutions to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can use a little bit of hack:

```
View c = listview.getChildAt(0);
int scrolly = -c.getTop() + listview.getFirstVisiblePosition() * c.getHeight();
```

But it will work correctly only if you will have same height for all list items.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. Firstly, the height of each list item is different and wouldn't this code give you the scrolled distance of the list and not the position of the scrollbar thumb on the screen?